# Get key-value from JSON data attribute

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a form in my Rails app which contains a select. Each option in the select has a data attribute `data-contact` with additional info I want to use in Javascript. The info is in JSON format, so if you look in the HTML code it looks like this:

```
<option data-contact="{"street"=>"Postbus 123", "street_number"=>"12", "zipcode"=>"6547 JN", "city"=>"Tilburg"}"></option>
```

Now I want to get the values from the keys, but the generated JSON by rails is different from the JSON expected by Javascript when you use the ``JSON.parse'' function. It expects the format to be like this:

```
<option data-contact="{"street":"Postbus 123", "street_number":"12", "zipcode":"6547 JN", "city":"Tilburg"}"></option>
```

In Javascript I use this to retrieve the values:

```
  var json = $('#invoice_contact_id option:selected').attr('data-contact');
  details = JSON.parse(json);
  alert(details.street);
```

How can I make this work? SHould I change something in the way Javascript parses the JSON, or should I change the way Rails formats the data to JSON?

Comment: Change the Rails output since it's not valid JSON.

Comment: `JSON` string is standardized. You need to replace `=>` with `:`

Comment: Agree, I changed the parsing in Rails to get valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Andy and @Java_user, but I also think the problem is that your output json contains quotes, so your `option` element is being parsed as this:

```
<option data-contact="{" street "=>" Postbus 123 ", " street_number "=>" 12 ", " zipcode "=>" 6547 JN ", " city "=>" Tilburg "}"></option>
```

To avoid this issue, you can encode your json data with base64 encoding beforing printing on your page and the decode when accessing via JavaScript:

**HTML**

```
<option data-content="eyJzdHJlZXQiPT4iUG9zdGJ1cyAxMjMiLCAic3RyZWV0X251bWJlciI9PiIxMiIsICJ6aXBjb2RlIj0+IjY1NDcgSk4iLCAiY2l0eSI9PiJUaWxidXJnIn0="></option>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var b64 = $('#invoice_contact_id option:selected').attr('data-contact');
var json = window.atob(b64).replace(/\=\>/g, ':');    // And this removes the problem of '=>'
details = JSON.parse(json);
alert(details.street);
```

Comment: Agree, I changed the JSON parsing in Rails to get valid JSON and then I am able to get the values in Javascript correct. I like your encoding option.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job

```
var jsonString = $('#invoice_contact_id option:selected')
                    .attr("data-contact")
                    .split('=>')
                    .join(':');
var details = JSON.parse(jsonString);
alert(details.street);
```